# Vba write in next cell if limit of one cell is reached

Tags: excel, vba

i have created a CSV to Json converter using VBA. To do so i crated the following Function:

```
  If parseAsArrays Then ' Check to see if we need to make our JSON an array; if not, we'll make it an object
    For rowCounter = 1 To rangeToParse.Rows.Count ' Loop through each row
        temp = "" ' Reset temp's value

        For columnCounter = 1 To rangeToParse.Columns.Count ' Loop through each column
            temp = temp & """" & rangeToParse.Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter) & """" & ","
        Next

        temp = "[" & Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1) & "]," ' Remove extra comma from after last object
        parsedData = parsedData & temp ' Add temp to the data we've already parsed
    Next
```

my "parsedData" sub is here:

```
Sub parseData()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b1") = toJSON(getValuesRange("Sheet1"), False) ' Set cell B1's value to our JSON data
```

End Sub

The code works great but sometimes the generated json is to large for only one cell. Therefore i want to create an if clause to write the json in two or more cells if the json is too large for one cell. Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the returned string based on the cell character limit in Excel which I think is currently 32767.

Something like the below could be a good starting point though you may want to extend your first function just to return an array and cut out the split string function here as it is undoing / repeating some of your initial work.

I use Cells(Row, Column) for the iteration through output columns as I find it more intuitive than offsets.

```
Sub parseData()

Dim xlCellMaxChar
Dim myRow
Dim myCol
Dim StrArr
Dim ColCounter

myRow = 1
myCol = 2

xlCellMaxChar = 32767
returned_string = toJSON(getValuesRange("Sheet1"), False)

If Len(returned_string) >= xlCellMaxChar Then
    StrArr = SplitString(returned_string, xlCellMaxChar)
    For ColCounter = 0 To UBound(StrArr) - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, myCol + ColCounter) = StrArr(ColCounter)
    Next
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(myRow, myCol) = returned_string
End If

End Sub

Public Function SplitString(ByVal str As String, ByVal numOfChar As Long) As String()
    Dim sArr() As String
    Dim nCount As Long
    ReDim sArr(Len(str) \ numOfChar)
    Do While Len(str)
        sArr(nCount) = Left$(str, numOfChar)
        str = Mid$(str, numOfChar + 1)
        nCount = nCount + 1
    Loop
    SplitString = sArr
End Function
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks but how can i go to the next cell if the limit is reached and continue with my json

Comment: So in this code you don't worry about the limit while you continue with your toJSON function and collect all data in one big string. When it is returned to Parsed Data sub it then sees how long it is and splits into the right number of cells. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Comment: sorry i missunderstood your answer. its working ! thank you very much